# Bibtex: Change formatting of editor name for type InCollection

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

I have a reference that is a chapter of the book, so I'd like to include both the author name and the editor's name in the citation. I quickly discovered that the "Book" and "InBook" types give errors when there are both author and editor names, so I changed it to "InCollection." However, I don't like the way it shows the editor piece. FYI, I am using the style apalike.bst. Right now my .bib file looks like:

```
@InCollection{Covich1993,
  Title                    = {Water and Ecosystems},
  Author                   = {Covich, A.P.},
  Editor                   = {Gleick, P.H.},
  Pages                    = {40--55},
  Publisher                = {Oxford University Press},
  Year                     = {1993},    
  Address                  = {New York},
  Type                     = {Book Section},    
  Booktitle                = {Water in Crisis}
}
```

Right now it displays like this in my bibliography:

[image]

...but I would like to rearrange how the editor appears so it looks something like this:

[image]

I attempted to find the right place in the .bst file to edit like I've done before for small changes, but this one is over my head.

Comment: It would be easier to do if you used `biblatex`, and more specifically `biblatex-apa`. The `author` and `editor` fields are accepted simultaneously by biblatex.

Comment: It would probably be easier with `biblatex` but it is a bit misleading to say that's because those fields are accepted together in that case. `bibtex` copes fine so long as you use `incollection` and `biblatex` will only cope properly if you use `incollection`. (`inbook` has a different meaning in the two cases but in neither case is it intended for items in anthologies as I understand it.) I actually had a bunch of entries similar to this break because I'd moved to `biblatex` from `bibtex`.